# represent 2d pile of ball in java

Tags: java, graphics, data-structures, location, 2d

I'm creating an application where I need to model (and display) a large number of 2-dimensional 'balls' (circles) using java. I've started by creating an `ArrayList` of `Circle` objects (a class that I defined, which has x/y pixel coordinates of the center of the circle, radius, color, and velocity in the x & y directions). I use a `java.util.Timer` object with a repeated `TimerTask` to control the motion of the circles. The circles vary in size from around 10-50 pixel radii.

What I want to happen is have balls fall from the top of the screen (randomly distributed across the x-axis) until they reach the bottom of the screen, which acts like a floor -- ball that reach it stop moving, and balls that reach stopped balls roll downhill on the other balls until they rest at a low/flat point. In the future I might want to make their behaviour a bit more complicated, so I want to create flexible code so I can easily expand. How it works right now is that every time period each circle check to see how close they are to every other circle. If there are no other circles nearby they continue falling normally. If two (or more) circles are close to each other there is code to determine how they will interact.

I have it working perfectly for small numbers of circles (< 200), but when I get larger numbers of circles (> 400) it starts slowing down significantly. I'm sure I can optimize some of the logic to make the comparisons a bit faster, but I was wondering if there are any ways of storing the circle in some structure besides an unorganized `ArrayList` that would let me easily find circles that are close to each other, so I don't have to do the N^2 operation of comparing each circle to every other one and, instead, just compare a circle to the 5-10 circles closest to it. For instance, I've considered using a 2D array to represent every pixel (or maybe square of 5x5 pixels) and store a circle where its center lies (so I could check if there are circles in any of the nearby cells, and ignore the rest). However, this still seems pretty inefficient as if I'm using a 800x1000 pixel canvas with 500 circles there would be a TON of empty spaces in the 2d array that I'd waste time checking. I've also considered some sort of hashmap, but I haven't thought of a great way to use that either.

So, can anyone think of an efficient way to store these circles that corresponds to it's location in 2d space and makes it easy to find nearby circles? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: this is often done with a QuadTree : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: This problem is called "collision detection in physical simulation". There is an enormous literature on it.  Try googling.  You're right that a simple 2d spacial hashing scheme will produce a big speedup on your particular problem.  You don't need one bin per pixel however.  Bigger bins will produce good speedups.

Comment: @Gene Thanks! I did try googling before posting, but I didn't know what to call the problem so the results weren't very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a QuadTree to find close neighbours. Or you can simply sort by one direction, which would be far easier to implement and should still allow you to reduce the number of candidate neighbours to a small window.

Comment: Thanks, the quadtree sounds like it could be very useful!

Comment: Quadtree will work great for problems where many items stand still. But when many items are all in simultaneous motion, perhaps not so well. Updates once per frame are far more expensive than the simple 2d grid of bins. Sorting once per frame is reasonable but should be done with an algorithm that performs well on "almost sorted data."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your idea of a 2D array is not so crazy. What I think you want is one List of all your circles, and a 2D array that would reference the circles also. So at each time, you can iterate over your `List<Circle>` to check each one. Each Circle has x,y coords and you only have to loop on your array for (x,y +/- 5). There is no need to check the whole possible space for Circles, because you already are keeping track of each Circle's center. Just grab the center, and check around it for other circles.